# How to handle the delay in $http.post in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using `$http.post` to get the data from `node.js` server. I want to handle the delay.

I had added timeout as `$http.defaults.timeout = 100;` and expected to `console.log` the delay in error but it is not working.

*Example:*

```
$http.defaults.timeout = 100;
$http.post(url, data).success(function(result) {
    callback(result);
}).error(function(error) {
    console.log("error");
});
```

I am new to `AngularJS`. Any help will be grateful.

Comment: You should use `.then(function(response) { })` with $http which returns a promise.

Answer (score 4):

The `$timeout` returns promise. The `$http.post` returns promise as well.

So I would use `$q.all`. [Documents](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q)

*Reference*

`$q.all([promise, …])` → `newPromise` 
`newPromise` will resolve once all the given promises have 
been resolved.

We can create some factory (or if you want to change it use can use provider):

```
.factory('delay', ['$q', '$timeout',
    function($q, $timeout) {
        return {
            start: function() {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $timeout(deferred.resolve, 100);
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

and now in controller we can write something like:

```
$q.all([delay.start(), $http.post(url, data)]).then(
    function(results) {
        // .....
    }, function(error) {
        // ....
    });
```

So you get response only if timeout stopped no matter how quick we get response from `$http.post`

Answer (score 2):

AngularJS $http accepts timeout as a one of the request parameters (more [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http))

Please have a look at this [post](https://gist.github.com/adnan-i/5014277) which explains how to implement the timeout functionality:

```
$http.post(url, { timeout: 100 })
        .success(success)
        .error(error);
```

Success as well as error functions accepts several parameters: `function(data, status, headers, config)`. When you get a timeout error, error handler will be executed and its status will be `0`.

I hope that will help.

Comment: **@Tom**, Thanks for the handy solution. When ll the delay happen if we pass the timeout parameter as you demonstrated? before or after the request?

Answer (score 0):

Check this one :

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
  .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.timeout = 5000;
}]);
```